# URL rewriting a subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdomain

Here is my question:

I am wanting to redirect users from one subdomain while serving files from the previous. For example, I want a user to access their account:

- Files are located at: `holonet.example.com/account/`
- I want the user's url to point to (display): `account.example.com/`

Another example:

- Files are: `holonet.example.com/account/user/reset`
- URL point (display): `account.example.com/user/reset`

---

I have been trying a couple of .htaccess ways but they have not been working. Here is my latest attempts: (.htaccess in publc_html):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(holonet\.)?thearmyoflight\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /account/$1 [L]
```

I then tried the following since the previous did not work -

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/holonet/account/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.  [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.thearmyoflight\.com$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /holonet/account/%1/$1  [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^account\.thearmyoflight\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/account/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /account/$1 [L]
```

This is assuming both domains point to the same document root. If not, you'll have to rely on mod_proxy:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^account\.thearmyoflight\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/account/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://holonet.thearmyoflight.com/account/$1 [L,P]
```